# In place editing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using Rais3 and [in_place_editing plugin](https://github.com/wanglian/in_place_editing).

Here is controller's code:

```
in_place_edit_for :name, :title
```

And here is index.html.erb:

```
<% @contracts.each do |contract| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= contract.name %></td>
    <td><%= contract.title %></td>
    <td><%= contract.content %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', contract %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_contract_path(contract) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', contract, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    <td><%= in_place_editor_field contract, 'name' %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

I have just added one line to the view:

```
    <td><%= in_place_editor_field contract, 'name' %></td>
```

I have got nex error code:

> Called id for nil, which would mistakenly be 4 -- if you really wanted
>   the id of nil, use object_id

Here is a [fill stack](http://pastebin.com/uhGEU5k9).

How can I fix this error?

Comment: But all other lines works.  For example: <td><%= contract.name %></td>

Comment: did you check what you have in the contracts table in the database in case there is some bogus data? does it work to comment out the `in_place_editor_field` line? also try selecting a smaller set for `@contracts` to see if say one contract in array works and such things.

Comment: If I will comment this line all works fine. The contract table contains only one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the controller should probably say

```
in_place_edit_for :contract, :title
```

assuming you have a contract model and want to inline edit title. Then also the view needs to be changed to reflect title and not name for the inline edit. Which field do you want to edit inline (both?)?

Along the lines of the plugin example:

```
# Controller
class ContractsController < ApplicationController
  in_place_edit_for :contract, :name
end

# View
<%= in_place_editor_field :contract, 'name' %>
```

**EDIT**

Change the view to have an instance variable

```
<% @contract = contract %>
<%= in_place_editor_field :contract, 'name' %>
```

Comment: I have changed the view to 'in_place_edit_for :contract, :name', but nothing changed.

Comment: Your syntax in the view is slightly different than in the example, i.e. you don't have the colon `(:)` in front of the model name.

Comment: I have tried but I didn't get success.  Here is all code https://github.com/demas/test_in_place_edit/blob/master/app/views/contracts/index.html.erb

Comment: Looked fine to me, but here is something: http://weeatbricks.com/2007/09/01/in_place_editor_field-method-in-ruby-on-rails/